# Pulando linha antes da hora

Tags: javascript, if, while

```
<script>

    var i = 0;

    while(i < 100){

        n = 1;
        resultado = n + i;

        if(0 === (i%10)){

            document.write(n + '-' + resultado + '<br>');

        }else{
        document.write(n + '-' + resultado + ' ');
        }


        i++;
    }
</script>
```

Estou digitando esse codigo para um exercicio, e ele ainda é parte do que quero fazer, mas encontrei um problema, ele esta dando o comando do if de pular a linha antes da hora, era pra ser somente no 1-10, mas ele faz isso no 1-1, espero que dê pra entender, me desculpem se me expressei mal, mas estou começando a estudar essa area agora, valeu!

Comment: tentei trocar a var i para 1 e mesmo assim, agora ele da break na linha 1-11 não na linha 1-10 como eu gostaria.

Comment: O zero dá true em "0 === 0 % 10" tens de juntar "&& i > 0". Queres que haja quebra de linha a cada 10 certo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como já te falaram nos comentários, a primeira iteração já resulta 0, por isso sua quebra de linha.

Se você iniciar em 1 e substituir o < 100 para: <= 100, irá funcionar o contador.

O código que testei:

```
<script>
    var i = 1;
    while (i <= 100) {
        if (0 === (i % 10))
            document.write('1 -' + i + '<br>');
        else
            document.write('1 -' + i + ', ');
        i++;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode apenas mudar o if para 0 === ((i+1)%10) e manter o resto de sua lógica.

```
<script>

    var i = 0;

    while(i < 100){

        n = 1;
        resultado = n + i;

        if(0 === ((i+1)%10)){

            document.write(n + '-' + resultado + '<br>');

        }else{
        document.write(n + '-' + resultado + ' ');
        }


        i++;
    }
</script>
```